# Spark - SQL query does not retrieve the same number of rows when using SELECT * or SELECT col1

Tags: sql, azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage

## Context

I am running an SQL query over PySpark, on top of an Azure Blob storage datalake. The lake is partitioned with several nested keys.

I ran two queries whose logic is the same to me regarding the filters, but actually query 1 returns 20 million rows, while query 2 returns 28 million rows.

Here is the structure of the blob storage container :

```
.
|-- company=first
|   |-- year=2021
|   |-- year=2022
|   |-- year=2023
|   `-- year=2024
|-- company=other
|   |-- year=2021
|   |-- year=2022
|   |-- year=2023
|   `-- year=2024
`-- company=second
    |-- year=2021
    |-- year=2022
    |-- year=2023
    `-- year=2024
```

### Query 1

```sql
-- File : query_1.sql
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM parquet.`abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/company=first/year=2023
WHERE col1 IN ('A','B','C')
UNION
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM parquet.`abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/company=second/year=2023
WHERE col1 IN ('A','B','C')
UNION
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3
FROM parquet.`abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/company=other/year=2023
WHERE col1 IN ('A','B','C')
```

### Query 2

```sql
-- File : query_2.sql
SELECT *
FROM parquet.`abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/company=first/year=2023
WHERE col1 IN ('A','B','C')
UNION
SELECT *
FROM parquet.`abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/company=second/year=2023
WHERE col1 IN ('A','B','C')
UNION
SELECT *
FROM parquet.`abfs://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/company=other/year=2023
WHERE col1 IN ('A','B','C')
```

### PySpark execution code

Here is the code used to run the Spark query from the SQL code

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

query1 = open("query_1.sql", mode="r").read()
df1 = spark.sql(query1)
df1.count()   # Gives 20 million rows

query2 = open("query_2.sql", mode="r").read()
df2 = spark.sql(query2)
df2.count()   # Gives 28 million rows
```

## Question

Any idea what could be the cause of this gap ? Anything related to using PySpark / PySpark over SQL / the SQL query itself / something in the data itself ?

Comment: UNION returns distinct values. Try using UNION ALL - if that gives the same count for both queries then that’s your issue

Comment: Thanks ! That's the right answer ! I just re-ran the query and it worked (and had the same count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @[NickW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13658399/nickw). Here duplicates seem to be the cause.

I have tried the following query where I have used `select *` with `union` and you can see I got 4 rows as output.

```
%sql
select  *  from One WHERE employee_name IN ('James','Maria','Jeff')
union
select  *  from Two WHERE employee_name IN ('James','Maria','Jeff')
union
select  *  from Three WHERE employee_name IN ('James','Maria','Jeff');
```

[image]

When I have tried your second case (`select column` with `union`), I got less rows.

```
%sql
select employee_name from One WHERE employee_name IN ('James','Maria','Jeff')
union
select employee_name from Two WHERE employee_name IN ('James','Maria','Jeff')
union
select employee_name from Three WHERE employee_name IN ('James','Maria','Jeff');
```

[image]

This is because, [`union`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-setops.html#union) removes the duplicates. In **Second case I have selected only `employee_name` and it has duplicates(row count will be 3 after removing duplicates)** whereas in the first case there won't be any duplicates because in that it is selecting all columns. This is same in your case as well. Check with `UNION ALL` as suggested in comments.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and example. Indeed @NickW was right and your explanation completed it, marking as answered !